# Is it possible to create a "tri-state" bottom sheet in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I've tried looking around everywhere through documentation, videos, and Stack Overflow questions but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

What I'm wanting is a Modal style bottom sheet that opens to a half expanded sheet. If the bottom sheet is swiped up, it fully expands the bottom sheet. If swiped down from half expanded it should collapse and just peek above the bottom of the screen. If swiped down from peek/collapsed state, it should close or hide the bottom sheet altogether.

Every bottom sheet from Compose that I've tried and seen only allows fully expanded, partially expanded, or hidden, but not also a peek. Or if it has a peek state, it cannot be swiped to dismiss.

`BottomSheetScaffold` appears to be a no-go, because I need to access and interact with content behind this Compose layout so the scaffold cannot be blocking (in this case) the map underneath the layout, unless there's a way to indicate/allow the scaffolding to pass clicks through to the underlying content.

I have seen the behavior in some XML bottomSheets with `STATE_COLLAPSED`, `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`, `STATE_EXPANDED`, etc. and I partially wonder if it would be easier to just slap an XML bottom sheet in an `AndroidView` that then takes composable content, though I'd like to avoid this if I can.

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the point regarding `BottomSheetScaffold`. From my understanding, BottomSheetScaffold is used to have a bottom sheet and main content which co-exist and can be both interacted with. Do you want to interact with stuff that is obscured by a bottom sheet?

Comment: Yes, sorry could've clarified that better. (Just for clarification in case I'm using the wrong nomenclature) `BottomSheetScaffold` asks for `sheetContent` (stuff behind/under the bottom sheet) and `content` (the bottomsheet itself). Its the `sheetContent` that blocks the content I need the user to be able to access (in this case a map behind it). Does this make sense?